# Solving the Theta and Value of X (Sine Law)

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

I have this kind of equation that I produced using the Sine Law when I was answering a physics problem. How can I solve the value of $\theta$ and the value of $x$?

Sample Equation:

$$\frac{x}{\sin(44^\circ)} = \frac{250}{\sin(16^\circ + \theta)} = \frac{200}{\sin(120^\circ- \theta)}$$

Comment: The last equality gives $\theta$.  Hence you get $x$ from the first equality.

Comment: Make orignal triangle with sides $x,200,250$ and angle $44,120-\theta,16+\theta$ respectively.Use cosine law on angle $44$ to find $x$.Once $x$ is find out You can find $\theta$ by taking $arcsin$ on both sides of equation $sin(16+\theta)=\frac{250 sin44}{x}$.

Comment: @user10354138 Don't you think calculating $\theta$ from last inequality is much difficult.